# How to make a number thresh hold using MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python

I want to make it so that the code only looks at a certain area in my graph. The chart doesn't change based on the line of the graph. I know there was a way to do it, but I can find it with Matplotlib.

```
xl = len(x)
zlx = int(xl) + 1
x.append(zlx)
y22 = current_stock # Other parts of my code 
y.append(y22)

plt.plot(x, y, linewidth = 2, 
    marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=7)  
# Here I want is so that the y is constant
plt.draw() 
plt.pause(1)
plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ylim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html) and [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) properties.